# complex django Query, I dont know how to do it

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a problem that is bursting my head and I could not solve. I don't know how to make a query using the Django ORM to get the correct result. I am using MySQL, The situation is as follows:

Models:

```
from django.db.models import Q,F,Sum, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

class Prestamo(models.Model):
    PENDIENTE = 1
    PAGADO = 2
    FUSIONADO = 3
    ANULADO = 4
    ESTADOS = (
        (PENDIENTE, 'pendiente'),
        (PAGADO, 'pagado'),
        (FUSIONADO, 'fusionado'),
        (ANULADO, 'anulado')  

        )

    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fecha_prestamo = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    capital_prestado = models.FloatField()
    meses_plazo = models.IntegerField()
    porcentaje_aplicado = models.ForeignKey(Interes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    valor_interes = models.FloatField(null=True)
    saldo_capital = models.FloatField(null=True)
    saldo_interes = models.FloatField(null=True)
    tipo_prestamo = models.ForeignKey(TiposPrestamo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    prestamo_nuevo = models.ForeignKey('Prestamo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank= True, null=True)
    #estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadoPrestamo, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, default=1)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADOS, default=PENDIENTE, blank= True)
    observaciones = models.TextField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0},{1},{2}".format(self.fecha_prestamo, self.cliente, self.capital_prestado)

class Abono(models.Model):
    prestamo = models.ForeignKey(Prestamo,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_abono = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    valor_abono_capital = models.FloatField()
    valor_abono_interes = models.FloatField()
    observaciones = models.TextField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadoAbono, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank= True, null=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0},{1}".format(self.fecha_abono, self.valor_abono_capital)


class Descuento(models.Model):
    prestamo = models.ForeignKey(Prestamo,default=None,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_descuento = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    valor_descuento = models.FloatField()
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    descontadopor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "descuento: {0}, {1}".format(self.fecha_descuento, self.valor_descuento)
```

In the database I have the following sample data for the tables related to the previous models.

Prestamo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqZ4b.png

Abonos
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUjRk.png

Descuentos
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAHW0.png

Through django ORM I am trying to obtain a list where each loan is shown by registration, the information I must show are: loan_id, capital_ borrowed, loan_date, percentage, customer, capital payments, discounts and capital balance

It has been really difficult for me to show the previous fields that are in bold since the values of both discounts and capital payments are doubled and of course this affects the capital balance field. This is due to the left join that automatically generates django ORM

I am using django updated and python 3.6, mysql 5.5

The django query I am using is as follows:

[Query mYSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5vOw.png)

However, the previous query using the ORM brings me the list with incorrect calculations.

I don't want to use sql queries, but use the ORM. But the SQL query that brings me the data as I need it is as follows:

And it brings me the following data:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9tM6.png

Where borrowed capital is the field that is in the Loan table, credit to capital, is the sum of payments that the loan has and are in the credit table, and discounts are found in the discounts table. Taking into account the previous data, I calculate the capital balance that meets the following mathematical formula: Capital balance = loan_value - (credits + discounts)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show the non-aliased function names you're using.

Comment: Fixed up, i edited the question, so I added functions imports